# Calculate slope of a time series dataframe for each row

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy, statistics

I have a dataframe containing time series data on a per year basis.

```
Dates 2015 2016 2017 2018 2019 2020
Data1 130  120  160  150  230  250
Data2 120  150  140  170  180  190
.
.
.
```

I want to calculate the slope for each row of the dataframe using least square regression ( the x-coordinates are the year columns, and the y-coordinates are the data contained in each column)
and also a standard error, both are defined as:

> [image: Slope formula]
>
> [image: Standard error formula]

where n denotes the number of data points (**6 in the previous example**), xbar is the **average of the years**, ybar **average of each row** (ie: ( 130 + 120 + ...)/6 for the first row).

So for each row 2 new columns would be appended one for the slope and one for the standard error.

I am trying to define a function that I then would use with the apply method on the original dataframe.

```
def slope_computer(data: pd.Series) -> float:
    #getting the dates ( in string type ) and cast them to float
    x_values = [float(value) for value in data.index]
    x_mean = sum(x_values)/len(x_values)

    #getting the actual data (that differs from one row to the other) as a list
    y_values = [y for y in data]
    ymean = sum([y for y in data])/len(data)

    numerator = sum([(x-xmean)*(y_ymean) for x,y in zip(x_values, y_values)])
    denominator = sum([(x-xmean)**2 for x in x_values])

    return numerator/denominator
```

Is there a more efficient way or built-in methods to alleviate the steps used ?

Answer (score 0):

I think we can make the process more efficient. If you can provide the data or part of it for a better evaluation.

Depending on the size of the data we can convert it to int16, int32, use .map or numpy.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).